# Quickblox Video call Session creation in iOS

Tags: quickblox, videocall

I am unable to create session for a user even user logged into the account.

here is my code:

```
 //Create new session
  let session = QBRTCClient.instance().createNewSession(withOpponents: opponentsIDs, with: conferenceType)
        if session.id.isEmpty == false {
             self.session = session
             self.sessionID = session.id
        guard let uuid = UUID(uuidString: session.id) else {
                     return
        }
```

the opponentsIDs I am passing from UsersDataSource()from Quickblox
conferenceType is .video

respone: 2021-03-12 15:31:11.888 rtc::[RTCClient] You have to be logged in in order to use Chat API

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to be connected to chat before creating a call session. Here is their guide - https://docs.quickblox.com/docs/ios-chat-connection#connect-to-chat-server

QuickBlox WebRTC signaling goes over XMPP protocol (that's why you have to be connected to chat first)